# Problem with interface Python and Cpp with OpenCV and Cuda

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm facing an issue while interfacing python and cpp. I need to compute an optical flow with the GPU. To do so, I'm using the tvl1 algorithm with opencv on with cpp and cuda.

My cpp code is working well with GPU and I now want to call the function in my python code because there isn't a way to compute optical flow on GPU with this algo on Python.

I'm using ctypes to make the link beetwin cpp and python. Here are my codes :

python

```
from ctypes import cdll
opencvfunc = cdll.LoadLibrary('opt_flow_lib/test.so')
```

cpp

```
//test.cpp

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C"

#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudacodec.hpp"

#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include "opencv2/core/mat.hpp"

using namespace cv::cuda;
using namespace cv;

DLLEXPORT int tvl(int a, int b) {

  int bound = 20;

  Size new_size(224, 224);

  Mat curr_gray, prev_gray, prev_image, curr_image;
  Mat flow_x, flow_y;

  GpuMat d_frame_0, d_frame_1;
  GpuMat d_flow;

  cv::Ptr<cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1> alg_tvl1 =           
        cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1::create();

  return 3;
}
```

Here is how I build my cpp file :

```
gcc -o test.so -shared -fPIC test.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

Here is what I have when I launch my python code :

```
OSError: opt_flow_lib/test.so: undefined symbol:   _ZN2cv4cuda20OpticalFlowDual_TVL16createEdddiididdb
```

When I remove this line from cpp :

```
cv::Ptr<cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1> alg_tvl1 =           
            cuda::OpticalFlowDual_TVL1::create();
```

Everything is going ok, I have my 3 int returned. But it seems that cuda doesn't want to do its job

Is someone who had ever turned opencv with cuda with ctypes and cpp/python could hepl me ?

Thanks you

EDIT :

Maybe it could be interesting to have my $ pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs :

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect
```